# Is there a way to modify a specific attribute of every jquery object in one call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically.... I am using this code

```
var editorLinks;
editorLinks = $(".admin_editor_link.html");
$.each(editorLinks, function(i, link){
    $(link).html($(link).attr("data-loadedtext"));
});
```

And I am wondering if there is some way to do it without the $.each call... like...

```
editorLinks.html($(this).attr("data-loadedtext"));
```

I assumed this would work (or some variation of it that I cant remember) but when I tried it all elements html was set to the data-loadedtext of the first element in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function supplied to `html()`:

```
   editorLinks.html(function(){
        return $(this).attr("data-loadedtext");
   });
```

The return value of the function is used as the value for `html()` *for each element*.

Using your example HTML in comment:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/taesc0tt/2/

Comment: Thanks! That is pretty much what I was looking for. I was hoping there was a way to just use 'this' without a function but that is still an easy call. If you are still curious the HTML is really simple, I basically just have a few of these `<button type="button" class="admin_editor_link html" data-loadedtext="Main Content Editor" data-toedit="1"></button>`. My first attempt was `editorLinks.html(editorLinks.attr("data-loadedtext"));` but... yeah...

Comment: Down-voter: care to explain why you have downvoted a correct working answer with working example?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but you'll need to change the name of your class to `admin_editor_link` because jQuery selector is trying to find elements with both `admin_editor_link` and `html` classes. (Unless, of course, you actually looking for elements with both those classes - your question has no HTML code to verify that - in which case you're fine).

```
<div data-loadedtext="1" class="admin_editor_link"></div>
<div data-loadedtext="2" class="admin_editor_link"></div>
```

Just use a function to return the result

```
var editorLinks = $(".admin_editor_link");

editorLinks.html(function () {
  return $(this).attr("data-loadedtext");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0y2rf9qv/13/)

[DEMO with both classes](http://jsfiddle.net/0y2rf9qv/14/)

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for elements with both. I actually have a few different types of "editors" and the class determines the type (html, text, db)

Comment: Cool, that second demo has what you want.

Comment: Amusing how your JSFiddles have my code and not yours :)

Comment: Nice spot. I changed it to `data` in a previous iteration of the demo and forgot to change it back again.